# Change Border Background property on Selection

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, background, listbox

I would like to change `Border.Background` when the ListBox's `ListBoxItem` is selected.

I made this resource in App.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="HighlightStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>

                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFE20080" />
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Strange, it works with `Foreground`, it changes the color, but it's not working with Background, and that is what I want to change.
The Background property is not set in XAML, so there is no local default value there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the Background in your style, in a setter. The reason for the animation not running could be that the brush from the theme is frozen. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509(v=vs.110).aspx

--- EDIT ---
Sorry, it was late last night when I answered and I missed a couple of things :) The most important of those is that this question concerns Windows Phone.

First, you don't need to animate the color, you want to replace the brush - that would be more efficient.

Second, you might want to change the background on the list box item, instead a particular component of it.

The following lines achieve this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
    <Storyboard>
      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFE20080" />
          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
      </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Then, you have a hardcoded value ('White') on your container control component. Make it inherit the value from the list box item instead, like this:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I've tried and edited the code above, please take a look.

Comment: I've tried your code, added one more attribute:
Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
Then it won't do anything. With Foreground it is good again, but not with Background.

Comment: I don't have a WP7 to try this... but did you have to add the TargetName? Did it not work without it? In other XAML environments, that syntax would target the background property on the templated element. I am not aware whether this is not supported on WP7.

Comment: It crashed without the TargetName so I've added it. Strange that it works with Foreground so the syntax should be good.

Comment: Alright... in this case, try 'LayoutRoot' for TargetName and set the background on 'ContentContainer' to '{x:Null}' or 'Transparent'. It is probably a weird little bug in the runtime.